# On Linux, which IDE can provide debug output in a separate window for a dual-monitor setup?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, debug, ide, development

Problem: I want to have the debug window (namely the call stack, variables, etc.) on the second monitor, while having the source code on the first monitor. The OS is Linux, preferrably Fedora, the compilers are GCC and / or Clang.

With Qt Creator, there seems to be no real way to achieve this since "open in new window" opens a bare window with no controls like those that apepar with `Alt-0` or the mode switcher.

With KDevelop, the various views are located in QT dock widgets, and while those can be torn off to float above the main window, they aren't real windows of their own, i.e. they have no titlebar, and will fade out when the parent window loses focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLion is able to arrange the debug pane into a separate window.